# How to make UIPopoverController visible at startup in portrait orientation?

Tags: ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, uipopovercontroller

I'm making an iPad application using a UISplitViewController. I want the masterView visible in a UIPopoverController when the app starts (and only when it starts) in portrait mode. If I use the `presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:permittedArrowDirections:animated:` method in the `splitViewController:willHideViewController:withBarButtonItem:forPopoverController:`
delegate function, I get the following error, when I start the app in portait mode:

Popovers cannot be presented from a view which does not have a window.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The particular error says that you must add the view to a window before showing the popover, not the other way round. Try sending `presentPopover…` from the application delegate's `-application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` after adding the view to your app's window.

Comment: It works but the only strange thing is that the popover shows some 40 pixels lower than when you push the barbuttonitem later on...

Comment: It may happen because the view hasn't performed layout with its final bounds. Try sending the view controller's view `layoutIfNeeded` after adding it to the window.